# Insert data into different tabels

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, phpmyadmin

I´m trying to insert data into diferent tabels with php, but dosent get it to work.

Heres my db structure: 1

```
Table: event
Structure:  FromDate | ToDate | locationID
```

Heres my db structure: 2

```
Table: jointable
Structure:  EventID | locationID
```

The thing i want to do more specific, i have inputs for "Fromdate" and "todate" and "locationid". I want to input fromdate and todate into table1, and locaionid to table2

Here is my sql query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO event (FromDate, ToDate, locationID)

VALUES ('$_POST[startdate]','$_POST[enddate]','$_POST[locationID)");
```

Any idea how i can "sort out" locationID to input it on my jointable instead?

Excuse for my bad enlish, i hope you understand what im trying to do.

Comment: means, you want to add locationID in both tables. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `events` VALUES('".$_POST["startdate"]."','".$_POST["enddate"]."','".$_POST["locationID"]."')");
```

Call another query for inserting into other table:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `jointable` VALUES('','".$_POST["locationID"]."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Write 2 different queries

Something Like This :

```
$startDate = $_POST[start_date];
$endDate = $_POST[to_date]
$locationId = $_POST[location_id];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO event VALUES ('$startDate','$endDate','$locationId");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO jointable VALUES ('','$locationId')");
```

**Note : mysqL_* functions are being depreciated . Avoid the,**